# Schedule 2 cron jobs

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

How do I cron 2 tasks like below (I actually want 2 cron jobs run in 30 seconds difference.)

```
cron:
- description: task1
  url: /task1
  schedule: every 1 minutes from 10:00 to 14:00

- description: task2
  url: /task2
  schedule: every 1 minutes from 10:00:30 to 14:00:30
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cron Jobs themselves don't allow seconds to be specified.  However, you could use [The Task Class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks) and set a countdown amount on task2 equal to 30 seconds.

I don't think this timing is guaranteed, but it should work approximately well.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Before I use cron, I used to use deferred.defer (one kind of Task Class ???? that you recommend). It works for about 30-50 cycles and then return an error. I tried to fix the error, but it is too difficult, so I must use cron job (crying)

Comment: Oh dear.  I just know what should be possible :) In Java Task 2 could additionally do a Thread.sleep for 30 seconds, so it waits 30 seconds until it executes.  However, by the time an instance has started / Google's infrastructure has started and processed the request I really only think you will get an approximate start time 30 seconds later.